# Get execution time from log using bash

Tags: bash, logging

I have some application that produce log file and at the end of file I have total processing time like:

> Processing done in 45.00031 sec

I can get this line using:

```
cat app.log | grep "Processing done in"
```

But how to parse string to get only number of seconds?

> 45.00031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pattern is set you can just use `cut` to select the 4th field from a space-delimited table:

```
cat app.log | grep "Processing done in" | cut -d " " -f 4
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` again for `only` numbers and dot

```
cat app.log | grep "Processing done in" | grep -oE '[0-9.]+'
```

Be careful, it might stop working in another locale, that uses `,` as decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

Or, in 1 process instead of 3

```
 sed -n 's/^Pr.*in //;s/ sec//p' app.log
```

**output**

```
45.00031
```

IHTH